# How to add date condition in @StreamListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Assuming, I am able to send messages through Kafka or RabbitMQ and consume them with @StreamListener.

Binders are configured for content-type = 'application/json', so I guess it would be possible to add conditions on the payload.

My requirement is to get elements only when a field's date is before now(). All other elements will be consumed when this condition will be true.

Example, I expect someting like:

```
@StreamListener(value = INPUT, condition = "data.startDate > now()")
public void onMessage(@Payload Data data) { 
    // ...
}
```

The first problem is I get the error :  EL1008E: Property or field 'startDate' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]' - maybe not public or not valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct since the payload is not converted to any type and exists in its raw form which is `byte[]`. Please see the [this section](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing) specifically *"Content Type Negotiation in the Context of condition"* sub-section.

However, for your case you can simply modify your expression to be something like `new String(payload)....`, knowing that it is always `byte[]` before it gets converted

Comment: Thanks Oleg. The section is not verbose about how writting condition from payload. Why should I parse the byte[] mysefl ? I can parse to String then to Object with JSOn, but it seems a little bit cumbersome ! Moreover, a simple example, even with a string condition, does not work because of the error I mentionned. I have added examples for clarification.

Comment: well, that is because we do not automatically assume user always wants a String, so until we know the type it is raw, hence `byte[]`. Also, your example is actually explained in the doc i posted. We can NOT possibly convert to `Data` object until we know that we're going to be invoking this handler. That said, I do feel like perhaps more clarification would be in order, so will try to update the doc

Comment: Indeed, you are right. That is what I just read in the doc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the documention and fit with Oleg's answer

> That is because you are testing something that does not yet exist in a
>   state you expect. That is because the payload of the message is not
>   yet converted from the wire format (byte[]) to the desired type. In
>   other words, it has not yet gone through the type conversion process
>   described in the Chapter 10, Content Type Negotiation.
>
> So, unless you use a SPeL expression that evaluates raw data (for
>   example, the value of the first byte in the byte array), use message
>   header-based expressions (such as condition =
>   "headers['type']=='dog'").